# Skipping first few lines in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark 2.0 code which would read .gz(text) files and writes them to the HIVE table.

Can i know How do i ignore the first two lines from all of my files. Just want to skip the first two lines.

```
   SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local")
              .appName("SparkSessionFiles")
              .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
              .enableHiveSupport()
              .getOrCreate(); 

  JavaRDD<mySchema> peopleRDD = spark.read()
      .textFile("file:///app/home/emm/zipfiles/myzips/")
      .javaRDD()
      .map(new Function<String, mySchema>()
        {
            @Override
            public mySchema call(String line) throws Exception
                {

                    String[] parts = line.split(";");
                    mySchema mySchema = new mySchema();

                    mySchema.setCFIELD1       (parts[0]);

                    mySchema.setCFIELD2       (parts[1]);
                    mySchema.setCFIELD3       (parts[2]);
                    mySchema.setCFIELD4       (parts[3]);
                    mySchema.setCFIELD5       (parts[4]);
                return mySchema;

                  }
        });

 // Apply a schema to an RDD of JavaBeans to get a DataFrame
    Dataset<Row> myDF = spark.createDataFrame(peopleRDD, mySchema.class);

    myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("myView");

    spark.sql("INSERT INTO myHIVEtable SELECT * from myView");
```

UPDATE: Modified code

Lambdas are not working on my eclipse. So used regular java syntax. I am getting an exceception now.

```
 .....
  Function2 removeHeader= new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>(){
        public Iterator<String> call(Integer ind, Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("ind="+ind);
            if((ind==0) && iterator.hasNext()){
                iterator.next();
                iterator.next();
                return iterator;
            }else
                return iterator;
        }
    };

JavaRDD<mySchema> peopleRDD = spark.read() 
  .textFile(path) //file:///app/home/emm/zipfiles/myzips/
  .javaRDD()
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex(removeHeader,false)
  .map(new Function<String, mySchema>()
    {
    ........


Java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:268)
        at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:683)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.next(BufferedRowIterator.java:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.next(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.next(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:368)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:31)
        at com.comcast.emm.vodip.SparkSessionFiles.SparkSessionFiles$1.call(SparkSessionFiles.java:2480)
        at com.comcast.emm.vodip.SparkSessionFiles.SparkSessionFiles$1.call(SparkSessionFiles.java:2476)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that :

```
 JavaRDD<mySchema> peopleRDD = spark.read()
  .textFile("file:///app/home/emm/zipfiles/myzips/")
  .javaRDD()
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) -> {
                if (index == 0 && iter.hasNext()) {
                    iter.next();
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        iter.next();
                    }
                }
     return iter;
   }, true);
  ...
```

In Scala, it the syntax is simpler. For example :

```
    rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(2) else iter }
```

**EDIT :**

I modified the code to avoid the Exception.

This code will only delete the first 2 lines of the RDD, not of every files.

If you want to remove the first 2 lines of every file, I suggest you do a RDD for each file, apply the `.mapPartitionWithIndex(...)` for each RDD, then do a `union` of each RDD.

Comment: Please look at my updated code. index == 0 does it refers to rdd partition or each file? Actually i would like to remove first 2 lines from each file.

Comment: I updated my answer after your comment. I hope it helps.

Comment: Which would perform better - 1)Applying filter transformation (first two lines have some unique values which i can use for filter criteria) or the mapPartitionWithIndex and then joining RDDs?

Comment: No idea ... maybe try the 2 solutions and compare. I'm interesting in the comparison!